# spark on yarn; how to send metrics to graphite sink?

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark

I am new to spark and we are running spark on yarn. I can run my test applications just fine. I am trying to collect the spark metrics in Graphite. I know what changes to make to metrics.properties file. But how will my spark application see this conf file?

```
/xxx/spark/spark-0.9.0-incubating-bin-hadoop2/bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client --jar /xxx/spark/spark-0.9.0-incubating-bin-hadoop2/examples/target/scala-2.10/spark-examples_2.10-assembly-0.9.0-incubating.jar --addJars "hdfs://host:port/spark/lib/spark-assembly_2.10-0.9.0-incubating-hadoop2.2.0.jar" --class org.apache.spark.examples.Test --args yarn-standalone --num-workers 50 --master-memory 1024m --worker-memory 1024m --args "xx"
```

Where should I be specifying the `metrics.properties` file?

I made these changes to it:

```
*.sink.Graphite.class=org.apache.spark.metrics.sink.GraphiteSink
*.sink.Graphite.host=machine.domain.com
*.sink.Graphite.port=2003

master.source.jvm.class=org.apache.spark.metrics.source.JvmSource

worker.source.jvm.class=org.apache.spark.metrics.source.JvmSource

driver.source.jvm.class=org.apache.spark.metrics.source.JvmSource

executor.source.jvm.class=org.apache.spark.metrics.source.JvmSource
```

Answer (score 8):

I have found a different solution to the same problem. It looks like that Spark can also take these metric settings from its config properties. For example the following line from `metrics.properties`:

```
*.sink.Graphite.class=org.apache.spark.metrics.sink.GraphiteSink
```

Can also be specified as a Spark property with key `spark.metrics.conf.*.sink.graphite.class` and value `org.apache.spark.metrics.sink.GraphiteSink`. You just need to prepend `spark.metrics.conf.` to each key.

I have ended up putting all these settings in the code like this:

```
val sparkConf = new spark.SparkConf()
 .set("spark.metrics.conf.*.sink.graphite.class", "org.apache.spark.metrics.sink.GraphiteSink")
 .set("spark.metrics.conf.*.sink.graphite.host", graphiteHostName)
// etc.  
val sc = new spark.SparkContext(sparkConf)
```

This way I've got the metrics sink set up for both the driver and the executors. I was using Spark 1.6.0.

Comment: Can you give an example on how exactly you send some metric to graphite/grafana?

Answer (score 6):

I struggled with the same thing. I have it working using these flags:

`--files=/path/to/metrics.properties --conf spark.metrics.conf=metrics.properties`

It's tricky because the `--files` flag makes it so your `/path/to/metrics.properties` file ends up in every executor's local disk space as `metrics.properties`; AFAIK there's no way to specify more complex directory structure there, or have two files with the same `basename`.

Related, I filed [SPARK-5152](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-5152) about letting the `spark.metrics.conf` file be read from HDFS, but that seems like it would require a fairly invasive change, so I'm not holding my breath on that one.

Comment: Is it actually necessary to add those flags to the submit script? The documentation states that your `metrics.properties` will be picked up automagically if it can be found in `$SPARK_HOME/conf/`

Comment: Good point, @Freidereikhs. I think that `--files` is still necessary since you need the `metrics.properties` file to be shipped to every executor; based on the original question, it seems like the default `$SPARK_HOME/conf/` behavior is not working for @user3614090, but I yea I will make a note of that in my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Thinking on it further, it seems like that default will only work if each executor also has `conf/` directory that the `metrics.properties` file lives in. I'm going to leave the answer as is since it is more explicit and, as I mentioned before, it seems like the default behavior is a little tricky and already not working for the OP.

Comment: Now I get it, I was wondering why it worked for me but indeed all the executors in my cluster have the `conf` directory :)

Comment: @RyanWilliams Is this working out for you? I tried this way, but when I specify "spark.files" as "/path/to/metrics.properties", it get's downloaded after quite some time on executor machines - by that time MetricSystem already throws an exception on filenotfound.